# insert an element after a number of ng-repeat iteration

Tags: html, angularjs

Is there a way to avoid such use of ng-repeat.
To fix the issue ,I used two ng-repeat using the option `limitTo` to display each 3 element separately.
What I want to do is ,to insert my elements and after each 3 elements ,So I add

```
<div class="row"> </div>
```

Below is my code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="row l-b-margin">
                <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="name in Courses|limitTo:3">
                    <div class="well well-white">
                        <img alt="R Programming" class="center-block l-b-margin"
                            height="100" ng-src="{{name.logo}}" width="100" />
                        <h6 style="text-align: center; color: #516979; font-size: 21px">{{name.name}}</h6>
                        <p class="text-space l-b-margin">Write your first code here</p>
                        <a class="rounded-button cta-border-button center-block m-button"
                            href="courses/introduction-to-r">Start Course</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="name in Courses|limitTo:-3">
                    <div class="well well-white">
                        <img alt="Data Manipulation" class="center-block l-b-margin"
                            height="100" ng-src="{{name.logo}}" width="100" />
                        <h6 style="text-align: center; color: #516979; font-size: 21px">{{name.name}}</h6>
                        <p class="text-space l-b-margin">Write your first code here</p>
                        <a class="rounded-button cta-border-button center-block m-button"
                            href="courses/data-table-data-manipulation-r-tutorial">Start
                            Course</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to add those new `.row` elements? Is it maybe an issue with styling? (sometimes if you have such grid of elements, some are shifting to next row due to differences in elements height - is this the case?)

Comment: @Mohamed check my answer hope it help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do is use `($index+1)%3==0` with ng-if and put the below element at the end of ng-repeat.

```
<div class="row" ng-if="($index+1)%3==0"> </div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HlvJL5z6triBtnLqGkPq?p=preview)
Hope it helps :)

Comment: same issue even using ng-if :(

Comment: Can you replicate your issue on plunker or fiddle

Answer (score 0):

What you're seem to be doing is trying to prevent this situation from happening: *(some blocks shifts to the next row if not all have equal heights)* [image: some blocks shifts if not all have equal heights]

If that's the case you can (and should;) ) fix it via simple css: (just add a custom class to the div your iterating over)

```
.my-block:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: it's not that exactly, what I want is to insert a row just after every 3 inserted elements. I tried to modify the style  `<div class="well well-white" style="margin=5;padding=5">` but i still have the same problem. I'm looking how to fix it via Angular :(